# How to remove banned.users in hadoop Hortonworks

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I have HDP Hortonworks 2.5.3 cluster, MAPREDUCE jobs in YARN are getting failed with the error:

> java.io.IOException: DistCp failure: Job job_1498784032636_0015 has
>   failed: 
>       Application application_1498784032636_0015 failed 2 times due to AM     Container for appattempt_1498784032636_0015_000002 exited with 
>   exitCode: -1000 For more detailed output, check the application
>   tracking page:
>   http://asterdart0005.labs.teradata.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1498784032636_0015 Then click on links to logs of each attempt. Diagnostics: Application
>   application_1498784032636_0015 initialization failed (exitCode=255)
>   with output: main : command provided 0 main : run as user is hdfs main
>   : requested yarn user is hdfs Requested user hdfs is banned

later i googled, it seems the hdfs user is banned user, as per the configuration in the file /etc/hadoop/conf/container-executor.cfg on each node, here is the content of the file:

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/local
yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/log
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop
banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin
min.user.id=500
```

I have modified the file in all nodes (namenode, edge and data nodes), as below:

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/local
yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/log
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop
#banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin
min.user.id=500
```

and restarted all services in HDFS, YARN and MapReduce2 through Ambari, after restarting my jobs are failing with the same error, and checked the /etc/hadoop/conf/container-executor.cfg content, looks it reset to initial stage as below:

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/local
yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/hadoop/yarn/log
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop
banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin
min.user.id=500
```

any idea whats the solution here, to remove the users from the banned users list?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is , you can not comment `banned_users` line, instead set correct users in value of `banned_users` list. (i.e. if you do not want to ban user `hdfs` then change `banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin` to `banned.users=yarn,mapred,bin`). If you comment `banned_users` list then anyway by default `hdfs, yarn and mapred` will be banned.

Another thing, you can follow steps given below to propagate changes to all nodes.

1. ​Go to Ambari server node
   Modify `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/YARN/<version>/package/templates/container-executor.cfg.j2` to configure banned users.
2. Restart Ambari server and all Ambari agents

Comment: Thanks for response @Shubhangi. I have modified /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/YARN/<version>/package/templates/container-executor.cfg.j2 and also other places where the container-executor.cfg.j2 exists like /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.0.6.GlusterFS/services/YARN/package/templates/container-executor.cfg.j2 , /var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6.GlusterFS/services/YARN/package/templates/container-executor.cfg.j2. </br> and i have restarted the amabari-agent, ambari-server, and services like - YARN, HDFS, Hive, MapReduce2. But still getting same error.

Comment: Here is Error: For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://asterdart0005.labs.teradata.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1499986622021_0016 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Application application_1499986622021_0016 initialization failed (exitCode=255) with output: main : command provided 0
main : run as user is hdfs
main : requested yarn user is hdfs
Requested user hdfs is banned

Comment: Thanks for update, unfortunately i couldn't test the solution because the cluster is not available any more, i will test and update if i get the cluster back. Thank you.